# query has_many through scope of join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i currently struggle with a query in rails.

I have two models that are connected via has_many through:

Basic Setup: multiple books can have multiple languages, and some of these languages are original_languages.

language.rb

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :language_books
  has_many :books, through: :language_books
end
```

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :language_books
  has_many :languages, through: :language_books
end
```

language_book.rb

```
class LanguageBook < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :book

  def self.original_language
    where(original_language: true)
  end

end
```

Database structure:

books

```
id | name
```

languages

```
id | name
```

language_books

```
book_id | language_id | original_language
```

As you can see, my join table is not only a join table but has an additional attribute (original_language).

What i want is the following:

I have a table in my view where i want to show every book. In this table, i also have a column named 'original_language', where i only want to show the original_languages of the book.
It is not a problem to get all languages for a certain book, but i don't know how to only show the original language.

It is not an option for me to change the database structure. For example include a "original_language" attribute into the books table directly would not work because i sometimes have multiple original languages.

What i work with at the moment is the following:

controller:

```
@books = Books.all
```

View:

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <% book.languages.each do |lang| %>
    <%= lang.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This code obviously shows every language for every book. 
Any ideas on how to achive what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `original_language` is a boolean. If not please add an example `seeds.rb` file.

If you can't change the table structure (which you should if possible) this is your solution:

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <%= book.language_books.where(original_language: true).first.language.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, it is boolean =) I would love to change the structure, i just dont know how. As is said i sometimes need multiple original languages. (customers..^^)  I will try your solution. But i guess this will result in alot of queries?

Comment: it would only do two queries if you use includes in the controller `@books = Books.includes(:languages).all`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you didn't place the relation in the best place, I think `original_language` would be better as id in the books table

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :language_books
  has_many :languages, through: :language_books
  belongs_to :original_language
end
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :language_books
  has_many :books, through: :language_books
end
class LanguageBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :books
  belongs_to :languages
end
```

If you want to stick with your current schema, you can add an additional relation with a scope

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :language_books
  has_many :languages, through: :language_books
  has_one :original_language, through: :language_books, class_name: 'Language', scope -> { where(original_language: true) }
end
```

Then add a nice delegation in the `Book` class

```
delegate :name, to: :original_language, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
```

and your call will become like this

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <%= book.original_language_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yea, you are totally right. The better place would be the books table, but as i said, i sometimes need more then one original_language. This is why i put it in the join table. Thanks for your answer though! Will try the other solution.

Comment: if you need more than one `original_language` then the second solution is the only way to go, just change `has_one` to `has_many`, the delegate won't work as good though, you'll need to tweak it

Comment: Yea, i guessed that =( But i still think that this is possible somehow. I mean, at some point, active record has to go through the join table and check the ids. I think it has to possible to also check for another attribute at this moment (original_language in my case).